# executeScript - inject prompt and return value - Failed to find value field

Tags: javascript, php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I try to test a login form with selenium where users have to enter a SMS code into the form for verification. I am using the [facebook/php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) Therefor I inject the following javascript into the site:

```
return prompt('Please enter the SMS verification code.', '');
```

This is how I try to catch the prompt value:

```
$smsCode = $this->driver->executeScript("return prompt('Please enter the SMS verification code.', '');");
```

According to the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/latest/Facebook/WebDriver/JavaScriptExecutor.html#method_executeAsyncScript), `executeScript` returns the script return value.

Now after this I want to send this code into a input field:

```
$SMSInput->sendKeys($smsCode);
$passwordInput->sendKeys(self::PASSWORD)->submit();
```

However, I get this error `UnknownServerException in WebDriverException.php line 114:
Failed to find value field`

I also tried to use `executeAsyncScript`.

I am using the latest Selenium Server V 3.0.1.

---

**Whole Test Script for Reproduction:**

*Note*: First install [facebook/php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver), read the installation instructions on the github page.
Then write the following php code into a .php file (e.g. index.php) and call the url, e.g. **localhost/selenium/index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Facebook\WebDriver;

use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;

require("vendor/autoload.php");

$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities::firefox(), 5000);
$driver->get('https://github.com/login');

$usernameInput = $driver->findElement(
    WebDriverBy::id('login_field')
);
$passwordInput = $driver->findElement(
    WebDriverBy::id('password')
);

$smsCode = $driver->executeScript("return prompt('Please enter the SMS verification code.', '');");

$usernameInput->sendKeys($smsCode);
$passwordInput->sendKeys('1234')->submit();
```

Comment: I didnot get how you can get code with this `$smsCode = $this->driver->executeScript("return prompt('Please enter the SMS verification code.', '');");` It is just opening `alert` popup on browswer and it doesn't return a sms code.

Comment: It does not start an `alert` it starts a `prompt` and returns the user input, which then will be available in `$smsCode`

Comment: I meant why you don't directly enter the smscode to `login_field` instead of getting it by prompt. Anyhow you must produce the smscode manually? how do you produce smscode?

Comment: The SMS code is a verfification code which I receive via SMS on my cellphone. This can take a few seconds until the SMS arrives me, therefor I have to wait and enter it manually. #2wayauthentication

Comment: if the case includes some manual step, you should not automated it.

Answer (score 2):

this appear to be an issue in Geckodriver, the Selenium implementation in Firefox - see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/431.

For the time being you can try either:

- latest Firefox (nightly version), where the issue *may* be fixed,
- or use Firefox 47.0.1 (or [Firefox ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/) version) together with Selenium server 2.53.1,
- or use different browser, like Chrome and [Chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/).

Comment: Do you know how I can pass Chromedriver to my selenium server?
I was able to pass Geckodriver to the server by starting it like this `start java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\GeckoDriver\geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar` but how does it work with ChromeDriver? Do i have to change `gecko` to `chrome`?

Comment: I just tried it with Chromedriver, I also get an error, but a different one `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\teschd\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\WebDriverKeys.php on line 105
`

Comment: I just tried it with Firefox ESR together with Selenium Server 2.53.1. Now I get `Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnexpectedAlertOpenException: Unexpected modal dialog (text: Please enter the SMS verification code.):`

Comment: The `executeScript()` method is not blocking, ie. the script execution will continue and will not wait until you submit the prompt. If you need to wait for the result, use `executeAsyncScript()`.

Comment: This makes no sense to me, Async should not block the execution instead, because it is asynchronous. However I just tried it with `executeAsyncScript` and get the error. `Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnexpectedAlertOpenException: unexpected alert open:`

Comment: The exception is surely weird. But it may behave differently in the new Firefox version, so I suggest trying it... And about the `executeAsyncScript` - it does not mean, the scirpt is executed asynchronously (ie. the selenium test will continue), but that the script expect asynchronous result, and the selenium test need to wait for the callback to be called - see executeAsyncScrip [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/latest/Facebook/WebDriver/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#method_executeAsyncScript).

Comment: I tested it also with the newest firefox version, same.